# PHP Fatal error: Cannot use ::class with dynamic class name

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I uploaded a website to a live server with this code

```
class Model extends Database
{
    public $errors = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        // code...
        if(!property_exists($this, 'table'))
        {
            $this->table = strtolower($this::class) . "s";
            
        }
    }
}
```

but I keep getting this error: PHP fatal error: cannot use ::class with dynamic class name
I've tried using the `get_class()` function but I don't think I'm using it properly, cause it takes me the controller not found page in the else block

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        // code...
        $URL = $this->getURL();
        if(file_exists("../private/controllers/".$URL[0].".php"))
        {
            $this->controller = ucfirst($URL[0]);
            unset($URL[0]);
        }else
        {
            echo"<center><h1>controller not found: " . $URL[0] . "</h1></center>";
            die;
        }
```

here's how I've been using it

```
if  (!property_exists($this, 'table'))
        {
            $this->table = strtolower(get_class($this)) . "s";

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

`$this::class` is non-sense, because you cannot use the scope resolution operator on an object's instance. Instead use the default predefined constant [`__CLASS__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) for the current class. Or function [`get_class(object $object = ?): string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) to get the class from any object's instance.

Comment: tried the suggested solution, nothing's changed, still the same result.

Comment: This wasn't the question, if you'd scroll up. I've added some debug output to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with [get_class()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

It seems that some versions of php don't support $this::class. It was implemented in [php version 5.5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php). but I am using php version 7.4.12 and it throws the error.